# How does one official know that a foreign country representative is the proper person to discuss some matters?

Tags: international-relations, israel, foreign-policy, romania

[The Romanian Prime Minister’s visit to Israel](http://abcnews.go.com/International/wireStory/romanian-president-blasts-pms-secret-israel-trip-54752955) triggered a serious political crisis in Romanian political life:

> Romania's president has slammed the country's prime minister for
>   embarking on a visit to Israel without his authorization.
>
> In Romania's division of power, it's **the president who is in charge of
>   foreign visits** and any foreign trips by the premier have to be
>   authorized by the president.
>
> The latest spat comes just a week after Iohannis said Dancila had
>   overstepped the mark in **saying Bucharest was ready to follow the U.S.
>   and move the country's embassy in Israel to Jerusalem from Tel Aviv.**

The crisis became so acute that the President [asked the Prime Minister to resign](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2018-04-30/netanyahu-to-disclose-significant-development-on-iran-pact-jgmcadz0).

I am interested in the perspective of the Israeli President, namely how could he know that he was meeting with a person who was not entitled to discuss such matters? Are these things checked before a high level meeting takes place?

**Question:** How does one official know that a foreign country representative is the proper person to discuss some matters?

Comment: That’s what diplomats are for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of the roles of a diplomat is to be an expert on the country to which they are sent.

It would be the job of the diplomats to advise the Israeli Prime Minister if there were any topics that should not be discussed, as they were ultra vires of the Romanian PM.

The extent to which this was done by Israeli diplomats prior to the Romanian PM’s visit is unknowable.